# Javascript vars in SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

The question it´s very easy , i need insert in SetTimeout the var for after this redirect to url , but the problem it´s for to take the value from var called redir :

```
    <script>
/// Var for redirect 
        var redir="action";
/// Set Time for redirect with the until var inside url
        setTimeout("location.href='?action=cp&load='+action",1500);
    </script>
```

The problem for me it´s with quotes because i have for SetTimeout put these quotes and for put the value of var redir i don´t know where put exactly

Thank´s

Comment: The string is *not* "interpolated". If could be written as: `setTimeout("..load=" + redir, ..)` (note that this results in a new string which is then passed as the argument). However, best is to *not* use the setTimeout(string) form. It's icky xD

Answer (score 7):

It is better to use an anonymous function in your setTimeout call. This is because a string will be constructed with the `Function` constructor which is similar to using `eval`. Moreover, using an anonymous function will allow you to use an easier approach to concatenating your string.

```
setTimeout(function(){
 location.href = '?action=cp&load=' + action;
},1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

A working sample

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var action = "redit";
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = '?action=cp&load='+action; }, 1500);
</script>
```

Comment: Although this works, prepending "window." to `location.href` doesn't make any difference (and consumes bytes that may slow down the page or make it more expensive). That difference in bytes is irrelevant if it's just once but it's good the get the habit of not writing "window". Also, indenting your code is a good idea since it improves readability and makes it easier to make further changes.